# Leetcode: Maximum score from performing multiplication operations

Tags: performance, rust

I am looking for feedback on how to make my code more performant (take less time) - specifically with a top-down approach.

My specific asks are:

1. How can I make this code faster? It currently takes around 170+ ms, but I see some solutions that are in the range of 10 ms.
2. I want to use a more functional approach to this - I want to write `memo.entry().or_insert_with_key()`, but I can't do that because memo needs to be recursively passed down to the subproblems. What can I do to use such a code structure?

Leetcode problem description:

> You are given two 0-indexed integer arrays `nums` and `multipliers` of size `n` and `m` respectively, where `n >= m`.
>
> You begin with a score of 0. You want to perform exactly m operations. On the ith operation (0-indexed) you will:
>
> - Choose one integer `x` from either the start or the end of the array `nums`.
> - Add `multipliers[i] * x` to your score.
>
>   - Note that `multipliers[0]` corresponds to the first operation, `multipliers[1]` to the second operation, and so on.
> - Remove `x` from `nums`.
>
> Return the maximum score after performing `m` operations.

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::cmp::max;

impl Solution {
    pub fn maximum_score(nums: Vec<i32>, multipliers: Vec<i32>) -> i32 {
        // State: s (start index for nums), e (end index for nums), k (number of operations remaining)
        // Subproblems: dp(s, e, k) = max(dp(s+1, e, k-1)+contrib(s), dp(s, e-1, k-1)+contrib(e))
        // Base case: dp(x, x, any >= 1) = contrib(x)
        // contrib(x) = multipliers[x] * nums[s/e]
        let mut memo: HashMap<(usize, usize, usize), i32> = HashMap::new();
        let m = multipliers.len()-1;
        Self::dp(0, nums.len()-1, m, &mut memo, &nums, &multipliers, m)
    }
    
    fn dp(start_idx: usize, end_idx: usize, num_ops_left: usize, memo: &mut HashMap<(usize, usize, usize), i32>, nums: &Vec<i32>, multipliers: &Vec<i32>, max_ops: usize) -> i32 {
        if !memo.contains_key(&(start_idx, end_idx, num_ops_left)) {
            let (from_start, from_end) = match num_ops_left {
                0 => (0, 0),
                _ => (Self::dp(start_idx+1, end_idx, num_ops_left-1, memo, nums, multipliers, max_ops), Self::dp(start_idx, end_idx-1, num_ops_left-1, memo, nums, multipliers, max_ops)),
            };
            memo.insert((start_idx, end_idx, num_ops_left), max(from_start + multipliers[max_ops - num_ops_left] * nums[start_idx], from_end + multipliers[max_ops - num_ops_left] * nums[end_idx]));
        }
        *memo.get(&(start_idx, end_idx, num_ops_left)).unwrap()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will not be commenting on the algorithm, as I've got no idea what's optimal. I will, however, be commenting on the code.

#### Leetcode...

First of all, it's just unidiomatic to:

- Create an empty struct just to associate functions to it, free-functions are perfectly acceptable in Rust.
- Take `Vec<T>` as parameter when not intending to modify the vector, `&[T]` should be preferred instead.

I do understand, though, that those are quite likely to be Leetcode artifacts... but `dp` is your own function, so `&[i32]` please.

#### Naming

The cost of calling a function is independent from the length of its name. Prefer meaningful names, then.

On the other hand, the `_idx` suffix is not very useful.

Oh... and an alias for that complex `HashMap` would be nice:

```rust
type MemoMap = HashMap<(usize, usize, usize), i32>;
```

#### Formatting.

The signature of `dp` is so long it runs off the side of the page. Use `rustfmt` (which you can invoke via `cargo fmt`) to format your code.

#### Simpler is better

Your use of `match num_ops_left` to check for 0 is unexpected, you can just use `if` really:

```rust
let (from_start, from_end) = if num_ops_left > 0 {
    (Self::dp(...), Self::dp(...))
} else {
    (0, 0)
};
```

In general, I advise using the simplest control-flow that works, so that when a more complex / less constrained control-flow form is used, it calls attention to itself "something special's going on here".

#### Redundancy is not helpful

You are tracking way too much state:

- In your hashmap.
- In the `dp` call.

Let's start with the hashmap: what's `num_ops_left` for? At any point in time, the number of operations left to do is equal to the number of multipliers to pick from, which itself can be deduced from:

```rust
multipliers.len() - (nums.len() - (end - start))
```

Hence, you can save space in your hashmap, and save time by not hashing redundant information.

Similarly, with regard to the `dp` call:

- As mentioned, `num_ops_left` is redundant, and can be eliminated.
- Similarly, `max_ops` is redundant.

Instead, you should pass `multipliers: &[i32]` and *trim* multipliers at each step so that you only pass the slice of multipliers left to use.

#### Avoid double-lookup, when possible.

You are correct that unfortunately you are not going to be able to use `.entry` *and* pass `&mut MemoMap` to compute what to insert... but that's the *rare* case.

The more frequent case should be that the entry *is* in the cache, and therefore you should vie to optimize this path.

This will also eliminate the very unfortunate `unwrap`, at the same time.

```rust
if let Some(cached) = memo.get(&(start, end)) {
    return cached;
}

let from_start = Self::dp(...);
let from_end = Self::dp(...);
let score = max(...);

memo.insert((start, end), max);

max
```

Now, there's only a double-lookup on unsuccessful cache hits.

#### Hash Flooding

Hash Flooding is a Denial of Service (DoS) attack which appeared in the 2000s. It was mostly used to take down websites, by crafting specific lists of HTTP parameters where all keys would hash to the same hashmap bucket, turning each insertion into an O(N) operation, instead of an O(1) one, and thus turning inserting all the parameters into an O(N<sup>2</sup>), rather than an O(N) one. As a result, popular languages such as Python & Ruby changed their default hashing algorithms to be more collisions resistant.

When Rust was created, it followed in its predecessors footsteps, and therefore *also* picked a more collision resistant hash algorithm by default (Sip2-4). Unfortunately, for you, it's not exactly a *fast* hash algorithm. And with hash lookups being a significant part of your workload, it's really something you should investigate.

My typical goto is the `fxhash` crate, which simply uses the FxHash algorithm with the standard `HashMap` implementation by defining a type alias. If you can't import it, you should be able to copy/paste part of the code, it's fairly lightweight.

#### Allocation & re-allocation

Rust collections are typically created empty, with no allocation. In the case of "contiguous" collections, they then follow an exponential growth pattern, where (roughly) the allocation size doubles each time an allocation is required.

In total, it means each element is roughly inserted once and moved once or twice. Not too bad. But not optimal, either.

Instead, you can use their `with_capacity` factory function to create a *suitably sized* collection from the get-go, and avoid intermediate reallocations.

You should be able to estimate the number of items to be inserted based on the length of `nums` and `multipliers` at the beginning, so just do it.

#### Revised code

*Note: the revised code uses `ahash` because it's available on the playground, I'd still recommend `fxhash` for simplicity though.*

```rust
use std::cmp::max;
use std::collections::HashMap;

use ahash::RandomState;

struct Solution;

impl Solution {
    pub fn maximum_score(nums: Vec<i32>, multipliers: Vec<i32>) -> i32 {
        // State: s (start index for nums), e (end index for nums), k (number of operations remaining)
        // Subproblems: dp(s, e, k) = max(dp(s+1, e, k-1)+contrib(s), dp(s, e-1, k-1)+contrib(e))
        // Base case: dp(x, x, any >= 1) = contrib(x)
        // contrib(x) = multipliers[x] * nums[s/e]
        let mut memo = MemoMap::with_capacity_and_hasher(
            multipliers.len() * multipliers.len(),
            RandomState::new(),
        );

        Self::dp(0, nums.len() - 1, &mut memo, &nums, &multipliers)
    }

    fn dp(start: usize, end: usize, memo: &mut MemoMap, nums: &[i32], multipliers: &[i32]) -> i32 {
        let Some((first, tail)) = multipliers.split_first() else {
            return 0;
        };

        if let Some(cached) = memo.get(&(start, end)) {
            return *cached;
        }

        let from_start = Self::dp(start + 1, end, memo, nums, tail);
        let from_end = Self::dp(start, end - 1, memo, nums, tail);

        let score = max(
            from_start + first * nums[start],
            from_end + first * nums[end],
        );

        memo.insert((start, end), score);

        score
    }
}

type MemoMap = HashMap<(usize, usize), i32, RandomState>;
```

[See it on the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=9e5c081e58aeee394ce61680402b71d4).

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response. Much appreciated!

Comment: @skittish: My pleasure, it was a fun problem to have a look at :)